# Как определить положение элементов в DOM относительно друг друга?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно в `JavaScript`/`jQuery` определить из двух элементов, в каком они положении в `DOM` относительно друг друга (первый над вторым или под ним)?

Comment: Сформулируйте поточней свой вопрос, что конкретно вам нужно. Как взять скажем 2-ой дочерний элемент и 4-ый и сравнить кто из них 1-ый, такой результат вы хотите видеть?

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант вам нужен?

```js
function example() {
  var a = $('#menu .active');
  var b = $('#menu .order');
  
  if (a.index() < b.index()) {
    alert('Элемент ' + a.text() + ' первый');
  } else {
    alert('Элемент ' + b.text() + ' первый');
  }
}

example();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="active">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="order">4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: не совсем то. Есть просто 2 элемента: `a = jQuery('.a');` и `b = jQuery('.b');`, например. Нужно узнать, какой из них в дереве `DOM` выше. А `index()` возвращает индекс в коллекции, но не в дереве `DOM`.

Comment: @nup ну прямой функции я не встречал, скорей всего это лишнее, вот бы видеть ваш `html` (хотябы пример расроложения этих 2х блоков, и тогда можно было бы попытаться сформулировать результат, может вы используете не тот подход при решении задачи?

Comment: `html` любой, и расположение элементов может быть любое, в этом и вся сложность. Не отрицаю, что могу использовать неверный подход. Задача, в том, чтобы написать функцию для замены двух элементов местами. Реализую при помощи `jQuery`, функция `insertBefore`, вставляю второй элемент перед первым. Есть другой способ - клонировать элементы и заменять ими друг друга, но этот способ вызывает проблемы с работой некоторых сторонних скриптов. Поэтому, удалять не хочется. Мой же способ меняет их лишь один раз. Для повторной замены, как раз, надо знать их позицию относительно друг друга.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const htmlText = document.querySelector("body").innerHTML;

let one = htmlText.indexOf("one");
let two = htmlText.indexOf("two");

if (one < two){
  console.log( "Первым идет элемент с классом one")
} else {
   console.log( "Первым идет элемент с классом two")
}
```

```html
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
```